# Azure SQL: Login failed for user (in cloud, not in local debug)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

So I have this connection string:

```
Server=tcp:{dbserver-name}.database.windows.net,1433;Database={db-name};User ID={db-admin-name}@{db-server};Password={admin-pass};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

And in the azure database server settings, I have granted my current client id to access it, as well as having ticked the 'Allow access to Azure services' box.

So, when I debug locally, I can connect and all's good.

But when I publish to azure and try to run it from there, I get:

Login failed for user '{db-admin-name}'.

Comment: Are you transforming your web.config between environments perhaps?  What does the effective web.confg look like in Azure?

Comment: Thanks! So there was a diff in the web.config, but I don't understand how that happened. The file on the azure site had an older connection string. But a change I committed later to that file (debug mode) was there.